# Text file reading input variables from txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I do have a text file in this format

```
instance_name = "small_instance_01_simple";
d = 2; 
r = 3;
SCj = [80 57]; 
Dk = [96 22 14];
Cjk = [[81 51 31]  [82 47 54]];
```

How can I get the value of those variables in my python code? I have tried more ways but it was unsuccessfully

Comment: _I have tried more ways but it was unsuccessfully_ Show us what you tried.

Comment: Are you able to change the text file format?  This would be a lot easier if it were a standard format like JSON.

Comment: Are you trying to read it into a dict with key/value pairs, or into program variables name "instance_name", etc.?

Comment: I can't. I need to work with .dat files

Comment: I tried with a dict but was a fail

Comment: @MrDan All of your responses would've been great in the actual question. Please provide the code you've tried, and failed with. Also the constraints you're working with. We're not omnipotent, we need more info!

Comment: Does this .dat file have a known format? Perhaps there is already a parser for that format out there somewhere. What program uses it?

Comment: If the format of these were at least valid python code, then you could have used ast.literal_eval to put the names and values into a dict. However since this is not valid python you would need to write your own parser to handle allthis

Comment: Do you want to read just that one file? What other syntax do you need support for - floats, units, integer separators, string escapes, booleans, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let us import `re` and define our file-like object:

```
import re

s = StringIO("""
    instance_name = "small_instance_01_simple";

    d = 2;

    r = 3;

    SCj = [80 57];

    Dk = [96 22 14];

    Cjk = [[81 51 31] [82 47 54]];
""")
```

The `parse_value` function try to parse the `expr` as primitive, if it fails as sequences and finally as strings:

```
def parse_value(expr):
  try:
    return eval(expr)
  except:
    return eval(re.sub("\s+", ",", expr))
  else:
    return expr
```

The `parse_line` function parse each line and returns the varaible name and value, if any:

```
def parse_line(line):
    eq = line.find('=')
    if eq == -1: raise Exception()
    key = line[:eq].strip()
    value = line[eq+1:-2].strip()
    return key, parse_value(value)
```

Now let extract the variables:

```
vars = {}
for line in s.readlines():
  try:
    key, val = parse_line(line)
    vars[key] = val
  except:
      pass
```

Let check what what we have:

```
for key, value in vars.items():
  print(key, value, type(value))
```

Output:

```
instance_name small_instance_01_simple <class 'str'>
d 2 <class 'int'>
r 3 <class 'int'>
SCj [80, 57] <class 'list'>
Dk [96, 22, 14] <class 'list'>
Cjk [[81, 51, 31], [82, 47, 54]] <class 'list'>
```